# Ruby / ActionMailer / Saving mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am creating a customer support app where clients can create, view, edit and comment support tickets.

I have this portion of the app working fine, but I want to have the data they submit into the ticket form emailed to me.

I have a separate "contact us" form that emails the data to me perfectly, but I want to combine the two forms into one.

It should work like this: client creates ticket, ticket is saved into the database, a copy of the ticket is emailed to me.

I can't figure out how to make all of these actions happen from one form.

Here is my tickets controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

def new
@ticket = Ticket.new
end

def create
@ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
@ticket.save
redirect_to @ticket
end

def show
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
end

def index
@tickets = Ticket.all
end

def edit
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])

  if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
    redirect_to @ticket
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
@ticket.destroy
redirect_to tickets_path
end

private
def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :help)
end
end
```

Here is my new ticket view:

```
<%= link_to "View an Existing Ticket", tickets_path, :class =>'btn btn-danger btn-sm'%>

<h1>New Ticket</h1>
<%= form_for :ticket, url: tickets_path do |f| %>
  <p>
  <%= f.label "Name:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
   <p>
  <%= f.label "Email:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :"Phone #:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :phone %>
 </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :"How can we help?" %>
  <p><%= f.text_area :help, :cols=> 38, :rows => 8 %></p>
  </p>
   <p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Submit Ticket</button>
  </p>
<% end %>
<p><%= button_to "Back", root_path, :class => "btn btn-danger btn-sm", :method => :get %></p>
```

Here is my email controller:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    if @message.valid?
     NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my email view:

```
<%= form_for @message, :url => contactcreate_path do |form| %>
  <fieldset class="fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :name %>
      <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :email %>
      <%= form.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :subject %>
      <%= form.text_field :subject %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :body %>
      <%= form.text_area :body %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Send" %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Ticket Model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base

after_create :send_new_ticket_to_email

 private

 def send_new_ticket_to_email
  NotificationsMailer.send_new_ticket(self).deliver
 end

end
```

Notifications Mailer:

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base

 def send_new_ticket(ticket)
  @ticket = ticket
  mail(:subject => "HelpDesk: #{message.subject}")
  default :from => "HelpDeskApp@ascendstudioslive.com"
  default :to => "Support@ascendstudioslive.com"

end
```

Let me know if there is anything else you would like to see. Basically, I want to have one form that saves a ticket to the database and then emails a copy of it out.

Thank you!

Comment: is there a reason your create method isn't creating?  i.e. why aren't you saving in your contacts#create method?

Comment: You can allways comment on your own posts.

Comment: I thought I was still logged in, but I wasn't. I can comment now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an after_create callback in your Ticket model to e-mail the saved ticket to yourself.

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base

 after_create :send_new_ticket_to_email

 private

 def send_new_ticket_to_email
  UserMailer.send_new_ticket(self).deliver
 end

end
```

and in your ActionMailer class:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

 def send_new_ticket(ticket)
  @ticket = ticket
  /* here you configure the variables for your email */
  mail(to: your@email.com, subject: 'New ticket...')
 end

end
```

then you will be able to use the @ticket object in your mailer views whatever way you please.

Comment: why the callback instead of sending it from the controller?

Comment: the same block can be reused in case he wants to email tickets in some other action. fat models skinny controllers applied here.

Comment: I tried that out and I am now getting: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input for my tickets controller.

I have gone through the whole thing and I can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: The error is pointing to:

`@ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)`

Comment: @Mavis makes a good argument for why to use the callback in this case, his answer is preferable to mine.  As for the syntax error, that just means you have an extra "end" somewhere which is just a typo, rather than being related to your core issue.

Comment: I resolved the other issues and it's working! Thanks Mavis and everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? I don't know if it is going to work, but all the same:

```
@new_message = NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message)
save_to_db(@new_message) # custom method to write it into your db somehow
@new_message.deliver
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what a contact is versus a ticket, but, broadly, the way to do what you want is, in your create action:

```
def create
  @message = Message.create(params[:message])) # create will save and validate the message
  if @message.valid?
    NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver # @message gets set to  
  # else...
end
```

Comment: I only made two separate forms because I couldn't figure out how to do it correctly. Ideally, I would get rid of contact and only have tickets saved to the db and emailed to me.